# What is the command in zookeeper to make a zookeeper leader voluntarily into a follower in a cluster?

Tags: python, apache, apache-zookeeper

I have four questions regarding zoo-keeper. Please give your inputs on this regard.

1. What is the command in zookeeper to make a leader voluntarily into a
   follower inside a cluster,which in-turn will make another follower
   machine in cluster to takeover a leader?
2. What is the procedure followed by zookeeper to do an election to form a leader inside cluster?
3. What is the command to check the cluster status in zookeeper, in turn I can say that, is there any command in zookeeper that cluster status for zoo-keeper is healthy and also the cluster formed successfully for zookeeper?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1) Zookeeper leader stepdown - good question, other than shutting the leader down and then brining it back up I'm not certain of any command to do that.

Question 2) Leader election: some discussion of that here:

> Leader Activation Leader activation includes leader election. We
>   currently have two leader election algorithms in ZooKeeper:
>   LeaderElection and FastLeaderElection (AuthFastLeaderElection is a
>   variant of FastLeaderElection that uses UDP and allows servers to
>   perform a simple form of authentication to avoid IP spoofing).
>   ZooKeeper messaging doesn't care about the exact method of electing a
>   leader has long as the following holds:
>
> The leader has seen the highest zxid of all the followers. A quorum of
>   servers have committed to following the leader. Of these two
>   requirements only the first, the highest zxid amoung the followers
>   needs to hold for correct operation. The second requirement, a quorum
>   of followers, just needs to hold with high probability. We are going
>   to recheck the second requirement, so if a failure happens during or
>   after the leader election and quorum is lost, we will recover by
>   abandoning leader activation and running another election.
>
> After leader election a single server will be designated as a leader
>   and start waiting for followers to connect. The rest of the servers
>   will try to connect to the leader. The leader will sync up with
>   followers by sending any proposals they are missing, or if a follower
>   is missing too many proposals, it will send a full snapshot of the
>   state to the follower.

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.2/zookeeperInternals.html#sc_leaderElection

Question 3) checking cluster status - you can try issuing one of the 4 letter commands at the client port, like this:

```
echo ruok | nc 127.0.0.1 5111
```

which will respond imok if all is well.

Full list of commands here: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.8/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkCommands

or run JMX: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.1/zookeeperJMX.html

Comment: 1) `delete /controller` via zkCli.sh